# How to make Springboot Interceptor read the requestbody without affecting the subsequent reading in the Controller layer

Tags: spring-boot, web, stream

In a Spring Boot project, how can we add an interceptor that allows us to read the contents of the request body within the interceptor without affecting the subsequent reading of the request body by the Controller layer? (If we directly call the getInputStream method to read the contents, the subsequent operations won't be able to read from the network stream anymore.)

I want to copy the request.getInputStream() as StreamA, then read StreamA to see something inside the original Stream when in the Interceptor layer.I don't want to modify the origin Stream and I want it can be read and operated by the Controller layer as usual just like I haven't done anything in the Interceptor layer.

Comment: You should use filters for this purpose. Refer documentation for creating filters in spring